# MVC contraint for anything that is only numeric

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I need help with a constraint:

```
Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(new { filename = @"" })
```

It has to be only numeric (no letters, slashes etc).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I understood the question, but as far as I know, you can simply provide regular expressions in the Constraints dictionary.

I think there is even an example for that in the [MSDN refguide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.route.constraints.aspx):

```
reportRoute.Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary { 
  { "locale", "[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}" }, 
  { "year", @"\d{4}" } };
```

based on that, I think what you have to write:

```
Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(new { filename = @"\d+" })
```

Comment: I think you're right, but you should probably use \d+ instead of \d* - the * allows no characters where the + requires at least one which is probably the intention.

Comment: You are right. I did not wanted to go into the Regex details, but \d+ is definitely more defensive than \d*. I have changed it.